# Php con MVC no funciona en Ubuntu ¿como hacer que funcione?

Tags: php, apache, mvc, ubuntu

Hice un proyecto en php con MVC, en Windows corre normal todo; instalé ubuntu con todas las herramientas,php, Apache 2, Mysql y funciona normal con un archivo php que este en una sola pagina, me conecta con la base de datos, pero el proyecto hecho con MVC no funciona, si navego a las paginas con la ruta normal, Proyecto/vistas/cliente/index.php la muestra, pero cuando pongo Proyecto/clientes que es la ruta con MVC no funciona y me dice que no se encuentra la página, ¿que puede ser esto?.  Ayuda por favor.

Comment: y si pones Proyecto/vistas/cliente/  ?

Comment: Activaste el mod_rewritte de apache? le diste los permisos necesarios a las carpetas que lo necesitan?

Comment: Gracias por responder, en windows funcionan las vistas normal, con MVC, pero en ubuntu es el problema,  los permisos ya estan, lo que dices del modo rewirite voy a revisarlo.

Comment: encontre la forma con sudo a2enmod rewrite, pero me dice orden no encontrada.  ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo manualmente?.  estoy en ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Gracias me sirvió el activar el rewrite mode, pero lo hice en /opt/lampp editando el archivo httpd.config, ademas de prestar atención a las mayúsculas.  Ubuntu maneja Case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en linux tienes que tener en cuenta "Case sensitive" no es lo mismo 
vistas/cliente/index.php que Vistas/Cliente/Index.php, verifica todas las rutas de tus archivos preferiblemente para que no te confundas maneja todo en minúscula

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, pero el lio no es ese, si no que al manejarlo con MVC, y rutas amigables no me funciona.

Comment: Gracias al final fue eso, en los controller los tenia en minúscula asi, personController, y en los Views, la carpeta contenedora estaba en mayúscula asi Person, solo era poner los nombres en minúscula.